# Parse, How to get the relation if the objectid isn't set

Tags: c#, parse-platform, relation

I have a problem where my relation keeps returning zero relational objects (in this case bank accounts).
Could someone take a quick look at my code and see if I'm doing something wrong?
The reason to the business logic in the property is due to a de-coupling of the database and the business logic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenFridge.Portable.Data.Interfaces.Entities;
using OpenFridge.Portable.Data.Parse.Entities;
using Parse;
using AutoMapper;

namespace OpenFridge.Portable.Data.Parse.Entities
{
    [ParseClassName("_User")]
    public class ParseUserEntity : ParseUserEntityBase, IUserEntity
    {
        private string _password;
        [ParseFieldName("password")]
        public new string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                base.Password = value;
            }
        }

        Lazy<IEnumerable<IBankAccountEntity>> _bankAccounts;
        [ParseFieldName("bankAccounts")]
        public Lazy<IEnumerable<IBankAccountEntity>> BankAccounts
        {
            get
            {
                var relation = GetRelation<ParseBankAccountEntity>("bankAccounts");

                if (relation == null) 
                    return null;

                var _bankAccounts = new Lazy<IEnumerable<IBankAccountEntity>>(() => relation.Query.FindAsync().Result);

                return _bankAccounts;
            }
            set
            {
                _bankAccounts = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that this keeps getting returned as empty due to the fact that
`this.ObjectId` hasn't been set yet before the BankAccounts code executes..
Any ideas of how to get this working?

Comment: where do you cal **BankAccounts** property? the position of the property usage inside your code will determine if it make sense or not

Comment: I will call it outside of the object itself, for instance in a factory,service or custom built repository or such.

Comment: when i asked "where do you call BankAccounts property?" i actually mean - **post some code**... you may use this property before initializing parse correctly